# Need help to make Menu shown on a site ( JQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to make a Menu as shown in below image[image]

see this [Link](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1836/Gooey-menu-plugin-with-jQuery) to go to its website i have copied some code ( HTML code and links to css and .js files) from there.

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="scripts/gooey.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/gooey.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <nav id="gooey-upper">
        <input type="checkbox" class="menu-open" name="menu-open1" id="menu-open1" />

        <label class="open-button" for="menu-open1">
            <span class="burger burger-1"></span>
            <span class="burger burger-2"></span>
            <span class="burger burger-3"></span>
        </label>


        <a href="#features" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Features" class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i> Item 1
        </a>
        <a href="#h-spaced-menu" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Horizontal Menu" class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-2x"></i>Item 2
        </a>
        <a href="#menu-v-example" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Vertical Menu" class="fa fa-arrows-v fa-2x"></i>Item 3
        </a>
        <a href="#docs" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Docs" class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>Item 4
        </a>
        <a href="#event-api" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Event API" class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>Item 5
        </a>
        <a href="#round" class="gooey-menu-item">
            <i title="Round Menu" class="fa fa-circle fa-2x"></i>Item 6
        </a>
    </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#gooey-round").gooeymenu({
                bgColor: "#ffc0cb",
                contentColor: "white",
                style: "circle",
                circle: {
                    radius: 85
                },
                size: 80
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded all the required files and even linked required .css and .js files to my code but i don't know why it gives me error that " It doesn't contain property googymenu "

Can anyone please help me to implement this Menu item.

Thank you so much.

**EDIT : Which file i need to add from all font-awesome files ?**

[image: Font-Awesome image]

Comment: You have 2 jquery files included in your code. Try removing the extra one. NOTE: Also remember to include `gooey.min.js` after `jquery.min.js`

Comment: I already tried that removing `<link href="scripts/gooey.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` gives same error and removing `<script src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>` will not recognize my JQuery script at all so i can't remove that file.

Comment: try adding only these 3 files in same sequence:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="gooey.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/gooey.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @HarshilShah I said you have 2 jquery files. 1. `jquery-2.2.3.js` and 2. `scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js`. One of these 2 is not required, you need to remove 1 of them. Now you have to decide which one is not required as we don't have access to your code.

Comment: i added these three files exactly in same sequence but than it gave me `0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`  so i added `<script src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>` and it gave me same error again :(

Comment: yea i tried that too. i used alternatively both files but by removig `jquery-2.2.3.js` gives $ error & by removing 'jquery 2.1.1.min.js' gives property error. 
i have link in my question you can have code and .css files if you want to see. http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1836/Gooey-menu-plugin-with-jQuery

Comment: Download [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) from the this link and then include the css in your project _The font path is relative from your compiled CSS directory_. so you would have to download it from their website and the above link has a Usin CSS method that you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine , see the sample.

**Edit**

Added Font-Awesome and a bit of CSS to move the menu.

```
#gooey-upper{
left : 200px;
top : 50px;
}
```

**Sample**

```js
$("#gooey-upper").gooeymenu({
   bgColor: "#ff6666",
   contentColor: "white",
   style: "circle",
   horizontal: {
     menuItemPosition: "glue"
   },
   vertical: {
     menuItemPosition: "spaced",
     direction: "up"
   },
   circle: {
     radius: 80
   },
   margin: "small",
   size: 90,
   bounce: true,
   bounceLength: "small",
   transitionStep: 100,
   hover: "#e55b5b"
 });
```

```css
#gooey-upper{
left : 200px;
top : 50px;
}
```

```html
<!--Jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--font awesome-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--plugin style-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2016/201604/20160421/jQuery-menu/css/gooey.min.css">
<!--plugin js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2016/201604/20160421/jQuery-menu/js/gooey.min.js"></script>

<nav id="gooey-upper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="menu-open" name="menu-open1" id="menu-open1" />

  <label class="open-button" for="menu-open1">
    <span class="burger burger-1"></span>
    <span class="burger burger-2"></span>
    <span class="burger burger-3"></span>
  </label>

  <a href="#features" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Features" class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#h-spaced-menu" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Horizontal Menu" class="fa fa-arrows-h fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#menu-v-example" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Vertical Menu" class="fa fa-arrows-v fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#docs" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Docs" class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#event-api" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Event API" class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#round" class="gooey-menu-item">
    <i title="Round Menu" class="fa fa-circle fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please tell me where i was wrong and where should i put your code in order to see correct output.

Comment: In your function, change your selector to : `$('#gooey-upper')`. because, that's what you have on your HTML code, : `<nav id="gooey-upper">`. Load jquery then gooey in that order. remove your second jquery library (jquert.min) and everything should be fine. Also dont forget to add font-awesome for icons.

Comment: i got little closer to my output but still it is not complete. i can see round button there but it is not expanding as shown in first figure. if i add links you mentioned in your code i can see button but if i add files i can't see round button. what are those link n script for ? and Is button expanding as you can see in image ?

Comment: @HarshilShah [here's](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) the cdn for font awesome(which gives you the icons). This is the [plugin's JS](http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2016/201604/20160421/jQuery-menu/js/gooey.min.js) and this is the [plugin's CSS](http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2016/201604/20160421/jQuery-menu/css/gooey.min.css). donwload them locally and use them. plugin's links are from plugins demo webpage

Comment: okay i will. i updated my question and i have font-awesome folder can you tell me which file i need to add and as i said before it still not working properly. i can see round button but it not expanding as you can see in menu.

Comment: did you try to make it in your VS ? if yes can you show me your output and exact code what you have written to make it work ? because i have tried all you said. i added those font files too. but it is not even showing round button but only a check box. and when i copy paste 4 links from your code it shows round button. i also tried those edited changes you mentioned in your answer. so can you please show your output and code ?

Comment: I have not used this plugin before this is the first time i've seen it but Give me few mins and i see what i can do for you. I will update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112358/discussion-between-amin-gharavi-and-harshil-shah).

Comment: [Here's a sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=56395271109932361524&t=5639527110993236152468499) I've made. Download and unzip it and you can see how it works.

Comment: It was browser problem. i was loading it in Internet explorer but when i try same in Crome it worked fine. Thanks for your all  efforts and suggestion to add required files.